# DirSource - empty directory despite correct file path

Tags: r, tm

Running an R script on a remote system (through SLURM.) I'm using the tm package to stopword out a corpus, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error in DirSource(cname) : empty directory
Calls: Corpus -> stopifnot -> inherits -> DirSource
```

Here is what I have in my script for my DirSource. (My .txt files are in the directory "corpus") I've also tried the file path without /corpus, but I still get the same error message.

```
cname = file.path("~/home/aej8qf/filesT/filesT/corpus")
docs = Corpus(DirSource(cname))
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant portion of your slurm script?

Comment: Did you figure this out?